# Conventions in naming the installation packages of a program?

Tags: software-installation

Are there some conventions in naming the installation packages of a program? That can help to decide which package to download and install on a computer system.

For example, rom http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.4.1/

```
[   ] hadoop-2.4.1-src.tar.gz     03-Nov-2014 11:54   15M  
[   ] hadoop-2.4.1.tar.gz         03-Nov-2014 11:54  132M
```

`hadoop-2.4.1-src.tar.gz` seems to indicate it is for installation from compiling source code.

Then what kind of installation is the one from `hadoop-2.4.1.tar.gz`? It is much larger, and I wonder it if is a cross-platform binary installation?

Can I install it on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

In my general use I've found:

- Linux source files (more rarely runnable programs) are any compressed form excluding zips, especially if they are gz or tar or any combination of the two.
- Linux packages are usually either deb or rpm extension
- Windows apps are usually in zip, exe, or msi form

To answer your particular question, this looks like a Linux source bundle that should be installable after building on 12.04 provided that you've installed the appropriate build libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu native install packages will end in ".deb".  Other packages are considered alien and would best be installed using the Alien package installer (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto).

Some programs may be packed in such a way where they may not pass the Alien check and can be installed just by extracting them and running them from the extracted directory.  Eclipse from the eclipse.org site is one of them.

To be more direct to the two that you mentioned, while I don't know specifically the packages, looking at the names, it would appear that one is the source code (hadoop-2.4.1-**src**.tar.gz) and the other (hadoop-2.4.1.tar.gz) is the binary distribution of the package.

If you download the source code you would have to actually compile the source.  Then use the instructions included with the package of running it after you have compiled and configured it.  The instructions for compiling the program will normally be included with the package.  Compiling from source may be quiet a challenge for novice users.

The binary version as I mentioned my be as simple as copying the files to where you want them and running it from there.  It'll also most likely have a "Readme.txt" file or "install.txt" file with instructions of how to install the package.

By the way, many packages that comes with the source will have a `configure` program included which can be run with the command `./configure` from that directory which will check if you have the needed dependencies to compile it, then prepare your system for the installation.  If the `configure` command is successful you can often install it by compiling with the make command `make` and install the compiled program with the command `make install`.

If the package can be installed using the `Alien` utility, you'd have benefit of having it listed in your installed package database as well as having the ease of conveniently using the standard Ubuntu uninstaller to cleanly remove it.